# An imperative program is analogous to how a Turing machine works?

Tags: turing-machines, computer-architecture, imperative-programming

Since Turing machines has great influence on typical hardware architecture (Von Neumann) and both uses concept of state, is correct to say that **an imperative program is analogous to how a Turing machine works**?

> “Computability via Turing machines gave rise to imperative
>   programming. Computability described via λ-calculus gave rise to
>   functional programming.” — Cooper, S. B., Leeuwen, J. (2013) . Alan
>   Turing: His Work and Impact.

And

> "Imperative programming languages such as Fortran, Pascal etcetera as
>   well as all the assembler languages are based on the way a Turing
>   machine is instructed: by a sequence of statements." - Barendregt, H.,
>   Barendsen, E. (2000) . Introduction to Lambda Calculus

Comment: I think it's an exaggeration. Modern hardware looks nothing like Turing machines.

Comment: The abstract machine model corresponding to imperative programming is the [Random access machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Neither in the sense that both uses sequence of statements?

Comment: Turing machines gave rise to *automatic programming*, which is what compilers use to parse code.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What you think about this: "Imperative programming languages such as Fortran, Pascal etcetera as well as all the assembler languages are based on the way a Turing machine is instructed: by a sequence of statements." - Barendregt, H.,  Barendsen, E. (2000) . Introduction to Lambda Calculus

Comment: I disagree with them. From the point of view of lambda calculus, perhaps Turing machines and RAM machines are on one side of the division, and lambda calculus is on the other. But in reality Turing machines are a very poor model for programming in general.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Even if it is not analogous to Turing machine, you think that an imperative code is like a imitation of how typical hardware works in the sense that is a subsequent layers of abstraction (differently from a functional code)?

Comment: Personally I am happy with typical hardware. Functional programming is a nice abstraction, but it isn't native to the physical world. At this point, I think we should stop having this comment discussion. You can wait for more serious answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a high enough level and when contrasted with functional programming, sure. Turing machine models and imperative programs have in common that they start from an input and take a series of steps that change a state stored in memory, ending with some output.

This contrasts with lambda calculus and functional programming which generally and loosely do not have the above features.

I think reading any more into the comparison than this, or trying to take it any farther, is probably a mistake. As Yuval says, Turing machines are quite different from modern machines and program execution environments.